# Case-insensitive string comparison in C

Tags: c, string, compare

I am trying to compare two strings to see if they are the same regardless of case. I've found a few functions. strcmp() is case sensitive but some others like stricmp() isn't in C and strcasecmp() dosen't seem to work either. Can anyone suggest a function in C which does this?

Comment: Have you trie `strncmp();`?

Comment: I believe that's case-sensitive, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks Markus, I checked but didn't see that one

Comment: One implementation: http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/xenocara/app/xedit/strcasecmp.c?rev=1.1&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup

Answer (score 0):

```
int iequals(const char* a, const char* b){
    unsigned int size1 = strlen(a);
    if (strlen(b) != size1)
        return 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
        if (tolower(a[i]) != tolower(b[i]))
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: @anatolyg : Thank you :)

Comment: sizeof doesn't return the length of string. But why reinvent the wheel

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc : Answer has already been edited. Now using `strlen()` to compute the size of string.

Comment: I felt like expanding this example. http://hastebin.com/vikepileka.coffee

Comment: @Dmitry : Great work :). I should have explained that much in my function.